# Iterating through every record in a field and trimming white space

Tags: filemaker

I'm trying to use the following script to replace each value in a field with the `Trim`med version of itself. The script runs fine, but I export all records afterwards and I still see white space - am I missing something?

```
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
    Exit Loop If [Let($c=$c+1;$c>Get(FoundCount))]
    Set Field [MyDataBase::MyField; Trim ( MyDataBase::MyField )]
    Commit Records/Requests [With dialog:On]
End Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I was missing a `Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next ]` inside my loop. Final working code is:

```
Go to Record/Request/Page [First]
Loop
    Exit Loop If [Let($c=$c+1;$c>Get(FoundCount))]
    Set Field [MyDataBase::MyField; Trim ( MyDataBase::MyField )]
    Commit Records/Requests [With dialog:On]
    Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next ]
End Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop script for such an operation. FileMaker has a function for this exact purpose.

```
Replace Field Contents [MyDataBase::MyField; Trim ( MyDataBase::MyField )]
```

Comment: Could you give an example using my sample field of `MyDataBase::MyField`?

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example

Comment: Interesting - almost looks too simple! I'll give that a shot. I have roughly 1300 fields to trim down - is there any kind of syntax for iterating through each field in a database?

Comment: 1300 fields per record? Ouch! You could step through the fields on the layout using the Go To Next Field script step, repeating the replace as you go. For this you could construct a loop that would stop after a certain number of iterations. This assumes that all required fields are on the layout and will follow the tab order.

Comment: Yes, 1320 to be precise - it's pretty insane. A whole data entry team has been free typing in this for years, and it's riddled with errors. I'm cleaning up everything for them now. And alright, I'll look into Go To Next Field a bit - thanks.

Comment: If there are many formatting errors in the text, including double spaces,extra returns, random text formatting,  you may be better off using one or more custom functions in your replace step to catch all these in one swoop. The built-in Trim is rather limited and only deals with leading and trailing spaces, not returns or in-string errors. I use the function NormalizeSpace a lot, in fact I have it as auto enter on most of my text fields. https://www.briandunning.com/cf/1933. In combination with TextFormatRemove you should get most cleaned away.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use a custom function called SuperTrim - someone poined this out to me on the forums as well. I also have the fields with the auto-enter calculation now, but I just have to retroactively fix some old mistakes.

Comment: Ok, be aware that Supertrim does not correct anything within the text, only leading and trailing white space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173989/discussion-between-dwirony-and-andreast).